# Outliers in Delta Time column, using data from wireshark

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, outliers, anomaly-detection

I am currently analyzing data downloaded from Wireshark, focusing on real-time network traffic. I need to perform clusterization on this dataset. However, during the visualization process, I noticed that there are outliers in the delta time. The mean of the data is 0.00045s, but there are some data points with values as high as 3s. In the context of clustering network data, should I treat these outliers as anomalies and remove them, or should I leave them as they are? Considering that in a network, there might be some long processes, I am uncertain about the appropriate approach.
"Delta time  is the elapsed time from the previous packet to the current packet"
[image]
[image]

Comment: Optimally you don't omit outliers, so think about what you want your clusters to represent. If delta_time is always >0 then you might consider a log-transformation.